# I want to show the all the available custom object, Standard object based on custom selection

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have some requirement to list out all the custom objects and standard object detail with label name and api name using VF page. If I choose "Custom Object", Then page should list out all the custom object with the column of label name and api name. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to replicate the functionality that already exists under the Setup pages for Objects and their detail pages?  What do you want the page to do?  Is it a VF page with a drop down of all the standard and custom objects that then shows all of the fields based on which one is selected?  What is your end goal?  Please give an example.

Comment: @RobDavis Let me explain you in scenarios, I have added picklist values as shown below `<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedOption}">
<apex:selectoptions value="{!objnames}"></apex:selectoptions>
</apex:selectList>` Assume that I have more than 30 custom objects. I need to display all 30 objects in pageblocktable with the column of **LabelName** **ApiName**. Please let me know if you got my points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your use case would be best suited to using the Schema.getGlobalDescribe method.  With this method you can get a list of all the fields for a given object.

Schema.getGlobalDescribe.get('Contact') returns a Schema.describeObjectResult object that can be further probed to get the field names and labels.  To get a Map of all the fields on the Contact object you could call:

```
Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Contact').getDescribe().fields.getMap()
```

From that result you could iterate over the map to display all of the results.  You would want to use an outputPanel with a nested repeat to produce the results.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. I tried Schema.getGlobalDescribe method to get all list of object.  I need to display all objects on the table based on object type selection. Say for the example, If I choose **Custom Object** picklist value, then I have to display all object's label name, api name related to **Custom Object** in Table. If I choose **Standard Object** then I have to display all standard related object details.